# ReactJS- Pass the JWT token as Authorization in axios method for http request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

I have an application where we are generating a JWT token and passing that token in Header in the next api call.As a response of that, I should get a key.I am able to see the response through postman.I am using ReactJS in Front End and trying to achieve the same by passing the JWT token in Header while doing the api call but facing some issues.
My code-

```
getKey() {
    let postData = {
      vin: "5678",
      id: "abc12",
    };

axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/generateKey",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: postData
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        setKey(response.data.key);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        getKeyError();
      });
  }

  memberAuth() {
    var self = this;
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/authenticateMember",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": localStorage.setItem()
      },
      data: {
        "id":"xyzzy",
        "password":"abc"
      }
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        //to do

  }
```

I am trying to save the generated token (valid for 30mins) in a localStorage/SessionStorage but not sure if this is the right way. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Create instance of your `axios`,

```
const agent = axios.create({
  baseURL: config.api_url,
  transformRequest: [transformRequest],
  transformResponse: [transformResponse],
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json' },
});
```

And then call this function to set headers dynamically

```
agent.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`;
```

Then call methods of your axios instance to make API calls

```
agent.get(`${endpoint}search`, { params }),
agent.post(`${endpoint}search`, JSON.stringify(body)),
```